# Python, FOR looping - creating lists

Tags: list, loops

This is my code to create lists, but its so brutal and inelegant, you guys have some idea to make it much smoother?

Thing is, I want to write code, where you could create your own lists, choose how many of them you want to create and how much items each should have - NOT using while loop. I can manage creating certain number of lists by inputing the range in for loop (number_of_lists)

```
    i = 0
    number_of_lists = input('How many lists you want to make?  >')

    for cycle in range(number_of_lists):   #this was originaly range(3), 
        item1 = raw_input('1. item > ')    #and will only work now pro-
        item2 = raw_input('2. item > ')    #perly, if n_o_l is exact. 3
        item3 = raw_input('3. item > ') 



                                           #everything is wrong with this
        print "-------------------"        #code, i need it much more au-
                                           #tonomous, than it is now.
        if i == 0:
            list1 = [item1, item2, item3]
        if i == 1:
            list2 = [item1, item2, item3]
        if i == 2:
            list3 = [item1, item2, item3]
        i += 1  


    print list1
    print list2
    print list3
```

Thing is I also want to avoid all that 'if i == int' thing.

Now it will only create 3 lists, right, because instead of number_of_lists i originally used integer 3 to make 3 lists.

Now you see my problem I hope. I need to create new lists from input and name them if possible, so instead of list1 i can name it DOGS or w/e.

I need it all much more simple and interconnected, I hope you understand my problem and maybe have some smooth solution, thanks :)

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Ok, I think I got it now - this is new version, doing pretty much what i want it to do:

```
    number_of_lists = input('How many lists you want to make?  >')

    allItems = []


    for cycle in range(int(number_of_lists)):
         items = []
         number_of_items = input('How much items in this list?  >')

         for i in range(int(number_of_items)):
                 item = raw_input(str(i+1) + ". item > ")
                 items.append(item)

         allItems.append(items)

         print("-------------------")


    print allItems
```

If anyone has idea how to make this more effective and clear, let me know here! :) thanks for help guyz

Answer (score 0):

You can add your lists to another list, that way it's dynamic like you want. Example below:

```
number_of_lists = input('How many lists you want to make?  >')

allItems = []
for cycle in range(int(number_of_lists)):
    items = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        item = input(str(i) + ".item > ")
        items.append(item)

    allItems.append(items)

    print("-------------------")


for items in allItems:
  for item in items:
    print(item)

  print("-------------")
```

You'd still need to check if `number_of_lists` is an `int` before parsing it into an `int`. If the user types a letter it will throw an error.